# What is the lifetime of the string returned by Tk_PathName()?

Tags: c, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am updating a piece of Tk-based third-party software for use with Tcl/Tk 8.6, and I have run across a statement of this form:

```
interp->result = Tk_PathName(tkwin);
```

, where `interp` is a `Tcl_Interp *` and `tkwin` is a `Tk_Window`.  It no longer being allowed (by default) in Tcl 8.6 to access the members of a `Tcl_Interp` directly, I want to convert that to a call to `Tcl_SetResult()`, along these lines:

```
Tcl_SetResult(interp, Tk_PathName(tkwin), /* what goes here? */);
```

But I'm having trouble finding any documentation of the lifetime of the string returned by `Tk_PathName()`, and I need to know that to specify the correct free function.

I suspect that the right thing to do would be to specify `TCL_VOLATILE` as the free function, so that Tcl makes and subsequently manages its own copy of the string, but that will produce a memory leak if the caller is responsible for freeing the string returned by `Tk_PathName()`.

If the caller has responsibility to free, then I suppose that `TCL_DYNAMIC` should be specified, though that does assume (I think reasonably) that Tk would have allocated the path name via `Tcl_Alloc`.

So which is it?  Or do I need something else, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, **Tcl *always* immediately copies the string you pass into `Tcl_SetResult()`**, regardless of the third argument, so that it can adopt the string into the managed `Tcl_Obj` infrastructure it uses internally. `TCL_VOLATILE` would be right… except that it simply doesn't matter any more!

There was a point where Tcl internally tried to support both ways of doing things; the code to support it was horrible and weird and it was genuinely hard to be sure by inspection that it was bug free so we switched to early copy, which was *absolutely definitely the right semantics and obviously so.* It probably also only meant that the copy was brought forward a tiny bit anyway, since nothing in the rest of Tcl could make use of non-`Tcl_Obj` results at that point.

That said, the lifetime of the string result from `Tk_PathName` is the lifetime of the widget and always has been for as far back as I've used Tk; the string is allocated when the widget is created, stored inside the widget's internal data structure, and deleted when the widget is destroyed. As such, `TCL_STATIC` is another candidate if you're not about to destroy the widget.

Comment: I have no idea why `TkNewWindowObj()` is not in the public API.